# Load razor view pages dynamically

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, razor-2

.Net loads all of my razor views at run-time, right off the bat and it takes forever to run locally, yet for my coworker, views are loaded lazily as called/needed and he can get up and running like lightning. This is really killing my development time. I've combed over the project files and the web-config. I set `<MvcBuildViews>True</MvcBuildViews>` in the proj file, but it doesn't really help to compile the views at build time, as they are then all still loaded on run.

Does anyone know how I can configure my environment to do this in debug mode? My coworker doesn't remember, and I can't find any suspicious settings.

Comment: asp.net by default compiles a view (and any partial views referenced by a view) on demand as the user hits certain routes. A view will only get compiled for the first time and then placed in cache for easy access each subsequent time. Remember though that the compiled view still has to be rendered each time a view is requested.

Comment: Is it your debug settings? Are you loading external symbols? Try setting JustMyCode = true in Debug options.

Comment: @rism, it's not that, I checked that already.